# Regex Expression to remove some whitespace with a look ahead and behind

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm working through a dataframe in python and cleaning up records. There are some with store numbers and slashes and whitespace that I need to remove. Leaving only a name and suburb.

An example of the text I'm working with is below:

```
Storename (Suburb / 1234     )
Storename (Surbub Suburb / 1234      )
```

I'm trying to get the regex to remove the spaces behind the closing bracket, but only up to the letters.

With the net result becoming:

```
Storename (Suburb)
Storename (Suburb)
```

I've been able to get the slash and numbers out with this:

```
test.LocationName.str.replace('[/0-9]','',regex=True)
```

But can't decode the regex to remove that whitespace behind the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
test.LocationName.str.replace('\s*/\s*\d+\s*','',regex=True)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/NexsdM/1/).

Comment: Here's an added complexity.
I've found some records that are "( Suburb name / 233)"
ie: space "after" the opening parenthesis

Comment: So I think it'll be a negative look ahead, something like this does part of it:
    \s(?!\()
But how do I get that to stop after getting to the first a-zA-Z?

@Jan

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub`:

```
re.sub("\((\S+).+?\)", "(\\1)", "Storename (Suburb / 1234     )")
re.sub("\((\S+).+?\)", "(\\1)", "Storename (Surbub Suburb / 1234      )")
```

Output:

```
'Storename (Suburb)'
'Storename (Surbub)'
```

Comment: Thanks for this one. The example I had above could have been clearer. The (Suburb Suburb) part was for suburbs with two words.